# How to change ghost speed in this code

Tags: java, performance

how would I adjust the speed at which the ghost moves in this code? Is the required code already there and i just need to change values? or do I need to add anything? I am fairly new to coding so please try to put this in easiest form possible. thank you.

```
package basicgame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaGame extends JPanel {

    int x, y;
  //  private Image dbImage;
    //private Graphics dbg;
    Image ghost;
    Image bg;

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
                if (x <= 8)
                    x = 8;
                else
                    x += -5;
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                if (x >= 435)
                    x = 435;
                else
                    x += +5;
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                if (y <= 18)
                    y = 18;
                else
                    y += -5;
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                if (y >= 325)
                    y = 325;
                else
                    y += +5;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public JavaGame() throws Exception {
        // Load images

        ghost = ImageIO.read(new File("ghost.gif"));

        bg = ImageIO.read(new File("myBkg.PNG"));

        setFocusable(true);

        // Game properties
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        x = 10;
        y = 10;

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                repaint();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(10,al);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // here, you have a 'drawimage' command for each object you're moving
        // if you have 2 players, you have another drawImage for that one
        // if you have a bullet, you have another for it. You have to keep
        //track of each object's x,y coordinates and then draw the image at that position.
        //you'll need some collision detection in there to see if bullets/players are
        //in the same position and then act accordingly.

        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);

        g.drawImage(ghost, x, y, this);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame f = new JFrame("Java Game");
                    f.setSize(500, 500);
                    f.setResizable(false);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                    f.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    f.setContentPane(new JavaGame());
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: By `speed` what do you mean exactly? According to your code `x`, and `y` should control the ghost coordinates, so adjusting those should be what you want.

Comment: 1. Find which variables the position of the ghost is stored in. 2. Find where these variables are changed. I advise going through some java tutorials, particularly if you are unable to complete these steps.

Comment: just increase the `5` of `x+=` and `y+=`, also create a speed constant for that value... so it is easier

Answer (score 0):

The position is stored in the variables `x` and `y`. The "speed" of movement is described simply by the rate of change of these variables on keypress; a brief look at the code shows that this "speed" is set, rather clumsily, to `5`. It appears in four different places--once for each direction vector. To change the "speed", you can just change all of these occurrences, but remember that if you forget to change some of them, the object will move at different speeds in different directions!

You could vastly improve this code by replacing all of your [*magic numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) with named variables. This includes not only the "speed", but also the movement boundaries: `8`, `18`, `435`, and `325`. Put these named variables inside the `AL` class or maybe the `JavaGame` class, depending on where they need to be available.

---

There's also an unrelated bug that I want to mention. Your current code will allow you to move out-of-bounds, and then on a subsequent keypress, move in the opposite direction indicated due to the "clipping". For example, say `x = 10`. If you press <kbd>Left</kbd>, you'll change `x` to `5`. If you then press <kbd>Left</kbd> again, the boundary condition will trigger and you'll move *right*, setting `x` to `8`. This is probably not desirable, so you should apply the movement first, *then* clip to the boundary.

Your `AL` class (consider a more descriptive name for this as well...) might then look something like this:

```
public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
    private static final int SPEED = 5; // Controls the movement speed in all directions

    // Variables controlling the movement boundaries
    private static final int BOUND_LEFT = 8;
    private static final int BOUND_RIGHT = 435;
    private static final int BOUND_BOTTOM = 18;
    private static final int BOUND_TOP = 325;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
            x -= SPEED;  // Move left

            if (x <= BOUND_LEFT) {
                x = BOUND_LEFT;  // If movement placed us out of bounds, move to boundary instead
            }
        }
        if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            x += SPEED;

            if (x >= BOUND_RIGHT) {
                x = BOUND_RIGHT;
            }
        }
        if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
            y += SPEED;

            if (y >= BOUND_TOP) {
                y = BOUND_TOP;
            }
        }
        if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
            y -= SPEED;

            if (y <= BOUND_BOTTOM) {
                y = BOUND_BOTTOM;
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```